# How to remove circular pink mailbox icon from tabbed activity template in android studio?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I have created a tabbed activity in android studio from the already provided templates. There is a pink button with the image of a mailbox. I have disabled it by deleting the java code which makes it display a temporary message. But I simply can't find where the button has been defined. I don't need it in my application and I want to remove it from the activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the code you deleted from the generated `onCreate()` method of the tabbed activity. Near the bottom was code like this:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
    }
});
```

If you follow the reference to `R.id.fab` in the first line, you'll come to the layout file for the tabbed activity. It's called `layout/activity_my_tabbed.xml` or something, depending on what you named the activity. In there you'll see a FloatingActionButton, something like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>
```

That's the button you're trying to remove. Delete that XML block.

Comment: this is the thing i cant find. lol. i dont know where it has hidden itself. anyway i'll use java to make fab invisible. that should solve my problem i suppose.